# HTTP Error 503, the service is unavailable Azure Virtual machine

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, http-error, http-status-code-503

I have created one Azure Virtual machine and installed all the IIS related roles and features.
After that I have created one Website in IIS.
I have given all the needed permissions to "Physical Path" and also configures https bindings.
The website gives "HTTP Error 503, the service is unavailable" error after few requests and responses are made on the website.

What could be the problem here? The Website works fine until any request-responses are made.

Comment: Not a surprise if this web site requires certain permissions but you missed them during deployment. Then any request can trigger application pool crash and the pool is disabled by IIS for server stability. 503 starts to serve by IIS ever since.

Comment: "The web site gives 503 after few requests", so it didnot give 503 after first request? Can you monitor it to get an accurate number of requests which make 503 appear? In azure virtual machine, can you check event viewer to get more information?

Answer (score 0):

Check the event viewer, there must be an exception caught from the application. Resolve and check it must be working.